# TypeError output seems backwards

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, encoding, typeerror

Here is a snippet to demonstrate my point:

```py
>>> type("test0@test1")
<class 'str'>
>>> type("test0@test1".encode("utf-8"))
<class 'bytes'>
>>> "test0@test1".split('@')
['test0', 'test1']
>>> "test0@test1".encode("utf-8").split('@')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Why does it tell me that a string operator requires a bytes-like object when it clearly requires a string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"test0@test1".encode("utf-8")` returns a `bytes` object.

[`bytes` has a `split` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.split) that takes something like a `bytes` object as an argument. But you are calling

```
"test0@test1".encode("utf-8").split('@')
```

So you are passing a string (`'@'`) to a method (`bytes.split`) that requires [a bytes-like object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-bytes-like-object) as its argument.

Hence the error `a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`.

Comment: Excellent answer, just for the OP as an example `"test0@test1".encode("utf-8").split('@'.encode("utf-8"))` you can split a bytes object by giving the bytes like object you want to split by. this gives `[b'test0', b'test1']`